# pandas to_csv is creating csv with sep = "|", but the read_csv only works with sep = ","

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax-error

I am working with a dataframe (testeEstadosSeparados) and when I want to save it as a csv file using "|" (or even ";") separator I am able to save the file but when I will read it, it just open when I set the regular comma as sep.

```
    testeEstadosSeparados.to_csv("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Bases/infraEscola-UF-semDuplicacoes/planosDeAcao_Escolas_{}.csv".format(pegaNomeDoCampo_Contagem(paths[0]),                                    index = False, sep = "|", encoding="utf-8"))
```

If I try to read as bellow it generate a error.

```
    pd.read_csv("/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/Bases/infraEscola-UF-semDuplicacoes/planosDeAcao_Escolas_MG.csv", sep="|", encoding="utf-8")
```

Error:

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 80, saw 2

Comment: Try to use `quoting` as parameter of `to_csv` and `read_csv`: `quoting=1` (or `quoting= csv.QUOTE_ALL`, don't forget to import `csv` module) then retry.

Comment: As a note on writing questions: Why this insanely long file name which makes the example hard to read? "test.csv" works too. And since you have a problem on line 80, use the data from that line to create a fully running example, including creating a dataframe with the problematic data.

Comment: You need `csv` module if you use `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` but it's not necessary if you use `quoting=1` (which is equivalent)

Comment: I am trying, but not succeed. Same error. Is it to set on df.to_csv only? or when try to read too? Thanks.

Comment: You must set it for both functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a noob problem.. I forgot to close a ")" in my function..